# How to combine hql check is null + hql if else condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am using hql to handle a complicated filter project API and have a "type" parameter in the FilterProjectByLocationRequestDto with this logic :

- If parameter "type" is null then find all project
- If parameter "type" is 1 then find all project with type = 1
- If parameter "type" is 2 then find all project with type = 2

I know that hql have these syntax

- isNull syntax: (param2 IS NULL OR col2 = param2)
- case syntax: case ... when ... then ... else ... end

But I only came up with the check null logic like below and don't know how to combine it with the case logic when type =1, 2. Please help me with this logic!!!. Here is the  object:

**ProjectRepository**

```
package com.levitate.projectbe.dao.project;

import com.levitate.projectbe.dto.filter.FilterProjectByLocationRequestDto;
import com.levitate.projectbe.entity.project.Project;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.QueryHint;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Project> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p from Project p " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.categoryBlocksList cb " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH cb.blocks bl " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.location l " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH bl.planList pl " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH pl.segmentList sl " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH sl.floorSegmentList fl " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH sl.segmentLayoutList sll " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH sll.layout layout " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.essentials e " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.tags t " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.facilities f " +
            "WHERE l.id = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.locationId} " +
            "AND fl.status = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.availableStatus} " +
            "AND fl.price <= :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.totalBudgetDto.max} AND fl.price >= :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.totalBudgetDto.min} " +
            "AND sl.viewStar = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.viewRating} " +
            "AND layout.bedroom = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.numberOfBed} " +


            // the logic I'm having trouble
            // the countQuery don't have this condition yet
            "AND (:#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getType()} is null or e.id = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getType()}) " +



            "AND (:#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getEssentialsList()} is null or e.id in :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getEssentialsList()}) " +
            "AND (:#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getTagsList()} is null or t.id in :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getTagsList()}) " +
            "AND (:#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getFacilitysList()} is null or f.id in :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getFacilitysList()}) ",
            countQuery = "SELECT distinct count(p) from Project p " +
                    "LEFT JOIN p.categoryBlocksList cb " +
                    "LEFT JOIN cb.blocks bl " +
                    "LEFT JOIN p.location l " +
                    "LEFT JOIN bl.planList pl " +
                    "LEFT JOIN pl.segmentList sl " +
                    "LEFT JOIN sl.floorSegmentList fl " +
                    "LEFT JOIN sl.segmentLayoutList sll " +
                    "LEFT JOIN sll.layout layout " +
                    "LEFT JOIN p.essentials e " +
                    "LEFT JOIN p.tags t " +
                    "LEFT JOIN p.facilities f " +
                    "WHERE l.id = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.locationId} " +
                    "AND fl.status = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.availableStatus} " +
                    "AND fl.price <= :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.totalBudgetDto.max} AND fl.price >= :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.totalBudgetDto.min} " +
                    "AND sl.viewStar = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.viewRating} " +
                    "AND layout.bedroom = :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.numberOfBed} " +
                    "AND (:#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getEssentialsList()} is null or e.id in :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getEssentialsList()}) " +
                    "AND (:#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getTagsList()} is null or t.id in :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getTagsList()}) " +
                    "AND (:#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getFacilitysList()} is null or f.id in :#{#filterProjectByLocationRequestDto.getFacilitysList()}) "
    )
    Page<Project> filterProjectByLocation(Pageable pageable, @Param("filterProjectByLocationRequestDto") FilterProjectByLocationRequestDto filterProjectByLocationRequestDto);

}
```

**FilterProjectByLocationRequestDto**

```
package com.levitate.projectbe.dto.filter;

import com.levitate.projectbe.dto.common.PopularFiltersDto;
import com.levitate.projectbe.dto.common.TotalBudgetDto;
import com.levitate.projectbe.enumeration.FloorSegmentStatus;
import com.levitate.projectbe.enumeration.SpecialType;
import com.levitate.projectbe.util.ApiUtil;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FilterProjectByLocationRequestDto {
    private final FloorSegmentStatus availableStatus = FloorSegmentStatus.AVAILABLE;
    Integer locationId;
    String totalBudget;
    TotalBudgetDto totalBudgetDto;
    String popularFilters;
    List<PopularFiltersDto> popularFiltersList;
    Integer viewRating;
    Integer numberOfBed;
    Integer type;

    Map<SpecialType, List<Integer>> sepratePopularFilterList;
    List<Integer> tagsList;
    List<Integer> essentialsList;
    List<Integer> facilitysList;

    public static void sepratePopularFilter(List<PopularFiltersDto> popularFiltersList, FilterProjectByLocationRequestDto dto) {
        dto.setSepratePopularFilterList(ApiUtil.getVariableSeparator(popularFiltersList));
        if (dto.getSepratePopularFilterList() != null) {
            dto.setTagsList(dto.getSepratePopularFilterList().get(SpecialType.TAGS) != null ? dto.getSepratePopularFilterList().get(SpecialType.TAGS) : null);
            dto.setEssentialsList(dto.getSepratePopularFilterList().get(SpecialType.ESSENTIAL) != null ? dto.getSepratePopularFilterList().get(SpecialType.ESSENTIAL) : null);
            dto.setFacilitysList(dto.getSepratePopularFilterList().get(SpecialType.FACILITY) != null ? dto.getSepratePopularFilterList().get(SpecialType.FACILITY) : null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Dattq2303 - if you have 3 separate queries with SAME names of output fields you can do `SELECT names FROM QUERY1 UNION SELECT names from QUERY2 UNION SELECT names from QUERY3`

Comment: @MrR this is an filter API so can only return the true result, i can't combine it

Comment: @MrR Sorry I understand what you mean now but it will generate 3 sql and it will be bad for performance cause generated sql is very long

Comment: well that is a different problem - although generally that sort of thing is less of an issue, than using the right query for the right problem. HOWEVER if this type is in java land you can choose in Java the different clauses - prior to handing to HSQL.

Comment: @MrR i'm think i will handle that logic in code instead of using hql for it. Thanks you for your help!